# Objective-C registering a class Runtime Reference

Tags: objective-c, class, objective-c-runtime

So I have a class `MyClass`. It's name is part of `char * myclasses[]`. I'd like to allocate it using the objc runtime api. 
1) Is this the best way to do this? My goal is to not allocate 10 or 15 ViewControllers, until they actually need to be used, and also not have a giant switch statement to create them.

```
Class aClass = NSClassFromString ( [NSString stringWithUTF8String:myclasses[1]] );
id myClass = class_createInstance(aClass, 0);
```

I'm trying to understand registering the class also..

2) Since I'm not creating a new class (just allocating) at runtime, I shouldn't have to register it, correct?
3) How does class registration normally work? (feel free to point me to a document somewhere).

Comment: Reading this more, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. You won't have to allocate any object instances until you call `[ [ <class> alloc ] init ]`. If you mean you don't want to load the classes until you need to alloc an instance of those classes--that's going to be tricky. You will somehow need to avoid referring to the class symbolically anywhere in your code, and even then I don't think you can avoid loading every class in your app under iOS. (iOS doesn't allow dynamic code loading)

Comment: @nielsbot The design was to have a single place where new controllers are added (by the controller class name as a C string), also be able to know which controllers are available (the array). Then later being able to create an instance of any of them (which was solved below).

Comment: In that case you could even do something like keep the list of class names in your app's plist... just a thought

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)
class_createInstance is not meaningfully different from +alloc. I would recommend just calling

```
[aClass alloc]
```

(and then `-init*` as usual, of course). No need to use ObjC runtime functions for normal allocation.

2) Right, no need to register

3) Dynamic class creation is a tricky business, but basically you allocate a Class (NOT an instance of that class) with `objc_allocateClassPair`, then add ivars and methods to it with `class_addMethod` and `class_addIvar`, then call `objc_registerClassPair` with it. After that you can use it as normal.

Comment: Thank you. Still not quite sure I understand the registering part. What does it accomplish? How do normal classes get registered?

Comment: they are registered by the runtime when your program loads

Comment: It adds that class to the list of classes. Normal classes are registered by the runtime itself, from the list of classes compiled into your application.

Comment: @estobbart These runtime functions add the new class to some internal storage (list) which is looked up by other functions. "Normal", so you call them, classes are registered by the compiler and by the dynamic loader, without using these runtime functions, directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have class names as C strings, you can do something like this:

```
const char * classNames[] = {
    "NSObject"
} ;

[ [ objc_getClass( classNames[0] ) alloc ] init ] ;
```

But you could just keep a list of NSStrings instead:

```
NSString * classNames[] = {
    @"NSObject"
} ;

[ [ NSClassFromString(classNames[0]) alloc ] init ] ;
```